# Nautilus no menu bar above Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nautilus

Hello my nautilus is missing the edit and go to options above in the toolbar when I hover the mouse above it. This happend since Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by installing nemo:

open the terminal and do this

First remove nautilus with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus
```

then download nemo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

then your folders might dissapear etc in the desktop. They should return after some time. If not the please restart the pc.

This is my solution. You don't have to delete nautilus but then you have to keep opening nemo and do all from there. BTW if you search nemo it will show you a application called files. Dont get confused on that, its still nemo.